# SharePoint Designer - wrapping webparts with html

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, web-template

Is it possible in SharePoint Designer 2013 to find the web part templates and wrap identifier div:s around them so I know what they are?

For example if I have a library web part and want to make them all blue, there seems to be no class that groups them in this way, however if I could wrap a div around the library template then I could achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

What you could do, is to use for example jQuery. There are elements lower down in the structure that has unique (well unique for all List View Webparts) classes.

Ex.

```
$('.ms-listviewtable').closest('.ms-webpart-chrome').addClass('tada-listview-webpart')
```

That code adds the class `tada-listview-webpart` to the most outer element of a List View Webpart.

By running this code after the rendering of the List View Webpart, you have successfully added a class and thereby can add styling to the webpart by the class name :)

Example of running after load of `sp.js`:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
    $('.ms-listviewtable').closest('.ms-webpart-chrome').addClass('tada-listview-webpart');
}, 'sp.js');
```

Not one hundred percent sure that `sp.js` is the script you need to run after, but you can see the load order in the developer tools of a browser, and try the scripts one by one until it works.

Comment: For example in a Content Editor Webpart, or if you have a custom masterpage, you can add a <script> there. Note that you will need to add jQuery for using my code. Btw, a thanks is usually connected to an upvote ;)